# Why gcc-4.9.2 can't support std::string.insert(iterator, range) to return iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.9

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert), C++11 should support:

```
template< class InputIt >
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

But when I try to compile following code using g++ 4.9.2:

```
std::string str{ "hello world" }, addition{ "h my" };
auto iter = str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin() + 4);
iter = str.insert(next(iter), addition.begin(), addition.end()); // Error
```

I receive the following error ([live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u179b0M9JimCNLXT)):

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >' and 'void')
 iter = str.insert(next(iter), addition.begin(), addition.end());
      ^
```

However, Visual Studio 2013 and Clang seem no problem.

Comment: GCC 4.9's `string` is not C++11-conforming in numerous ways; this is just one of them.

Comment: @T.C. where can I find out more details about this?

Comment: Looking at the function definition in 4.9.2, the first parameter type is `iterator` (pre-C++11) instead of `const_iterator`. Looks like it has been [fixed](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L1269) on libstdc++ trunk. Presumably destined for gcc5.

Comment: Didn't read the actual error you were observing. The culprit is not `iterator` vs `const_iterator` but the return type. The gcc4.9.2 version of this `insert` overload returns `void`.

Answer (score 3):

gcc used a non-conforming [copy-on-write (COW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) implementation in `4.9.2` they changed this in `5.x` series and we can see from a [live godbolt session](https://godbolt.org/g/rC35vP) that this is broken in `4.9.2` but works in `5.1`.

This change is documented in the [GCC 5 Release Series Release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html):

> A new implementation of std::string is enabled by default, **using the small string optimization instead of copy-on-write** reference counting.

We can find a description of the difference between the COW and SSO version from the [libstdc++ mailing list: New std::string implementation (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-11/msg01785.html):

> This is the long-awaited ABI break for std::string, **replacing our venerable Copy-On-Write implementation with a C++11-conforming Small-String-Optimization implementation** (based on Paolo's vstring).
>
> The gist of it is adding a second complete std::string implementation that is tagged with abi_tag("cxx11") so it mangles differently (as already done for std::list and std::ios_base::failure).